How to Handle Data Inconsistency Between Asynchronous Write and Read Operations in Heterogeneous Databases?
I'm working on a project developed with ASP.NET, using Blazor for the frontend and Web API for the backend.
In our backend architecture, we use heterogeneous databases for read and write operations:

Write Database: Each service has its own private database.
Read Database: A data warehouse that provides pre-aggregated cross-service data.

Here's the problem:

When a user performs an action on the frontend, the backend updates the write database.
The response is returned to the user immediately after the write operation.
The data synchronization to the read database is done asynchronously.

Due to this async process, there is a time window where the frontend might display stale data from the read database, leading to user confusion, incorrect actions, or repeated operations.

Directly reading from the write database to mitigate this issue is not feasible.
Considering a mechanism like a TraceId to track the update status and notify the frontend when the read database is updated.

Question:
What strategies can we employ to handle this inconsistency period effectively? Is using a TraceId a viable solution, or are there other design patterns or best practices that can help resolve this problem?
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

You can use a distributed cache. But the larger question is why use a database for analytics when you need read after write consistency?

"Time stamp" records as appropriate. You can then compare time stamps for "dirty" and "not dirty" reads.

@Salil Thank you, this is indeed something I've been reflecting on as well. Our project involves gradually refactoring an existing legacy system. Users need to observe multi-dimensional data to perform actions. Currently, the 'read database' relies on the original data source to ensure the old system remains functional. We're also planning to build a data warehouse to streamline multi-service data aggregation. Meanwhile, we're progressively splitting the 'write database' to isolate different data domains.
